# Remove NULL fields from JSON in Greenplum

Tags: json, greenplum

Using Greenplum 5.* database which is based on Postgres 8.4.

I am using row_to_json and array_to_json functions to create JSON output; but this ending up having keys with null values in JSON. Postgres latest version have json_strip_null function to remove keys with null values.

I need to import the generated JSON files to MongoDB; but mongoimport also doesn't have option to ignore null keys from JSON.

One way I tried it to create JSON file with null and then use sed to remove null fields from JSON file.

```
sed -i 's/\(\(,*\)"[a-z_]*[0-9]*":null\(,*\)\)*/\3/g' output.json
```

But looking for a way to do it database itself as it will be faster. Any suggestions how to render json_strip_null function in Greenplum without affecting the query performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've had the same issue in GP 5.17 on pg8.3 - and have had success with this regex to remove the null value key-pairs. i use this in the initial insert to a json column, but you could adapt however:

```
select
    col5,
    col6,
    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
    (SELECT row_to_json(j) FROM
        (SELECT 
        col1,col2,col3,col4
        ) AS j)::text,
    '(?!{|,)("[^"]+":null[,]*)','','g'),'(,})$','}')::json
        AS nvp_json
from foo
```

working from the inside-out, the result of the row_to_json constructor is first cast to text, then the inner regexp replaces any `"name":null,` values, the outer regexp trims any hanging commas from the end, and finally the whole thing is cast back to json.

Comment: I think it can be made more simpler using only one regex_replace as,  
`SELECT regexp_replace(row_to_json(e)::text, '((,*)"[^"]+:(null|"")(,*))*', '\4', 'g')
FROM employees e;`.  
This will also remove keys with empty values. I solved this problem using plpython function for myself as I answered below.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using plpython function. This generic function can be used to remove null and empty valued keys from any JSON.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_strip_null(json_with_nulls json)
              RETURNS text
              AS $$
    import json

    def clean_empty(d):
        if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
            return d
        if isinstance(d, list):
            return [v for v in (clean_empty(v) for v in d) if v not in (None, '')]
        return {k: v for k, v in ((k, clean_empty(v)) for k, v in d.items()) if v not in (None, '')}

    json_to_dict = json.loads(json_with_nulls)
    json_without_nulls = clean_empty(json_to_dict)
    return json.dumps(json_without_nulls, separators=(',', ':'))
    $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

This function can be used as,

```
    SELECT json_strip_null(row_to_json(t))
    FROM table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE to replace the nulls with an empty string or another value.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-conditional.html

The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often used to substitute a default value for null values when data is retrieved for display, for example:

SELECT COALESCE(description, short_description, '(none)') ...
This returns description if it is not null, otherwise short_description if it is not null, otherwise (none).
...